# Looking for batch file to open two specific files

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file that will look for the latest revision of a given drawing and configuration

When scanning through the map and the script found the latest revision, i want the script to open te latest revision and the second to last revision.

For example, in a map i have

0036255-002-003

0036255-002-002

0036255-002-005

0036255-002-004

I want the prompt to ask me the drawing number and the cnofiguration number, so i enter “0036255-002”

Now I want the script to scan through the map and figure out that 0036255-002-005 is the drawing im looking for with the latest revision. Now i want it to open both 0036255-002-005 and 0036255-002-004. (the last one and the second to last one).

This is the script i have, but it will only open the file with the latest revision. Then it wil tell me “The system ‘cannot‘ find the file lmax_file! .’”  Can someone help me out? Whatever I try, it seems to not be able to locate the second to last revision file…

```
@echo off

set /p "numbers=Enter the drawing number and configuration number: "

set "max_rev=-1"
set "second_max_rev=-1"
set "max_file="
set "second_max_file="

for /r %%f in (*%numbers%*) do (
  set "filename=%%~nf"
  set "ext=%%~xf"
  set "rev=!filename:*-=!"
  set "rev=!rev:*-=!"
  if !rev! gtr !max_rev! (
    set "second_max_rev=!max_rev!"
    set "second_max_file=!max_file!"
    set "max_rev=!rev!"
    set "max_file=%%f"
  ) else if !rev! gtr !second_max_rev! (
    set "second_max_rev=!rev!"
    set "second_max_file=%%f"
  )
)

if defined second_max_file (
  echo Opening %max_file% and %second_max_file%
  start "" "%max_file%"
  start "" "%second_max_file%"
  timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
) else (
  echo No files found matching %numbers%
)

pause
```

I’m not really experienced with batch files so all help is welcome and appreciated.

I ran the above mentioned code

It found the last revision, but it couldnt find the second to last one. Even if I tries a script where he only looks for the second to last one, it cant find it. So it feels like it has dificulties with the definition of “second to last one”

This is the script for only finding the second to last one I tried:

```
@echo off

set /p "numbers=Enter the oproepnummers and configuratienummers: "

set "max_rev=-1"
set "second_max_rev=-1"
set "max_file="
set "second_max_file="

for /r %%f in (*%numbers%*) do (
  set "filename=%%~nf"
  set "ext=%%~xf"
  set "rev=!filename:*-=!"
  set "rev=!rev:*-=!"
  if !rev! gtr !max_rev! (
    set "second_max_rev=!max_rev!"
    set "second_max_file=!max_file!"
    set "max_rev=!rev!"
    set "max_file=%%f"
  ) else if !rev! gtr !second_max_rev! (
    set "second_max_rev=!rev!"
    set "second_max_file=%%f"
  )
)

if defined second_max_file (
  echo Opening %second_max_file%
  start "" "%second_max_file%"
  timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
) else (
  echo No files found matching %numbers%
)

pause
```

This one didnt work as well...

All help welcome.

Eventually I want a batch file that will do the same but where i can input a list of drawings and configuration numbers, so it will open both last and second to last revision of all the requested drawings.
So if anyone can help with that as well, Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to batch as well, but perhaps my recent ventures into `for` loops can be of use.

Though not entirely clear the filetype, directory depth, or naming nonmenclature, I whipped something together that may help in your endeavors.  I'll admit I went a little cross-eyed at your variable usage (might just be me though), so I opted to simplify.

I used `notepad.exe`, though `start` can automagically open assigned file extensions and I don't typically find any issue with omitting the title parameter either.

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /P "userInputMapNo=Enter the map drawing no.:"
set /P "userInputConfNo=Enter the map configuration no.:"

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%A in ('dir /S /O-N %userInputMapNo%-%userInputConfNo%-*') do (
    call :mapSelection %%A %%B %%C
    )
call :startMapTools
exit


:mapSelection
for %%a in ("%3") do (
    if not defined workingRev (
        set "workingRev=%1-%2-%3"
        ) else if not defined latestRev (
            set "latestRev=%1-%2-%3"
            )
    )
exit /B

:startMapTools
start notepad.exe "!workingRev!"
start notepad.exe "!latestRev!"
exit /B
```

To start we set `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.  This will allow us to use variables as they're created in the `for` loop.  `%vars%` are parsed before the bat/cmd is run, so this is required to enable delayed `!vars!`.  With that out of the way we go into the `set /P`s.

In this case our `for` loop simply uses a `dir` and our `set /P`s can easily be wildcards. `dir /O-N /B *-*-*`, `/O-N` to sort **o**rder by **n**ame (reversed,"-"), with `/B` for **b**are listing, outputs:

```
0036255-003-001
0036255-002-005
0036255-002-004
0036255-002-003
0036255-002-002
0036255-001-009
0036255-001-008
```

We break this in the `for` loop into 3 seperate tokens delimited by '-': `"tokens=1,2,3 delims=-"`.  This gives us `%%A`, `%%B`, and `%%C`, which we pass to our `:mapSelection` function.  So let's say our `%userInput...No%` vars were `00*` and `*2` respectively, `dir` would parse:

```
0036255-002-005
0036255-002-004
0036255-002-003
0036255-002-002
```

`For` would set each delimit to a variable, thus...

```
%%A=0036255
%%B=002
%%C=005

%%A=0036255
%%B=002
%%C=004

etc...
```

The results of the initial `for` are passed to`:mapSelection` as parameters.  Then we run a loop over the `%3` variables, where you want the latest and greatest.  The pick out of the `dir` list is quite simple and can be accomplished with some simple `if` statements.  When the loop occurs on the ordered list `if not defined workingRev` the first value, `set workingRev` , else `if defined workingRev`, but second vars `not defined latestRev`, `set latestRev`.  The loop will parse the entire directory listing provided (narrowed massively by `%userInputs...No%`), setting the vars for the first two, but ignoring the rest.

Then we finish with `:startMapTools`.  This is the most important part and likely where you may be finding trouble (though tailing spaces and tabs can be equally frustrating).  For the `start` cmd to use our newly created `for` `!vars!`, this is where that `setlocal` comes into play.  `%vars%` will have odd results, being parsed before the `for` loop, and delayed `!vars!` must be used, thus: `start mapSoftware.exe !workingRev!` or `start mapSoftware.exe !latestRev!`.

I used notepad, on blank files with no extension, but the wildcard (*) in the `dir` will accept any.  If you have a specific extension in mind, you can hardcode it to the  `dir`, or make another `set /P userInput...=`.

The above is just an example, but hopefully you can pick something up from it.  You could even add a `/S` parameter to the `dir` cmd to recurse directories, however the above does not handle spaces in directory names. And further warning, `dir` does natural order counting, however your leading zeros help circumvent that issue.

Comment: @Kaz was this at all helpful?